# How to increase the actual size (Disk) of Oracle VirtualBox?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, java, oracle

I am using Oracle VirtualBox. I have installed the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4.
First I set the Disk space 10GB and now I have set the Disk Space 80 GB but box show actual size is 8.21 GB.
How can I increase the Actual size ?

NOTE : During the installation of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 I choose the Manual partition.

Should I need to change the partition if Yes then how ?

current Condition of Disk :

[Disk Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRE0s.jpg)

[spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UlFZ.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since this is being done to a VirtualBox drive, it's not too difficult at all. Here's how you can expand the partition size:

1. Boot the VM with either [an Ubuntu .iso](https://www.ubuntu.com/download) or a [GParted Live CD](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/livecd.php) image
2. Open GParted
3. Right-click on the partition you wish to expand.
4. Select "Resize"
5. Expand into all the free space
6. Click "Apply"

From there you can boot into your VM normally and find that your partition size has expanded properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply @Matigo
I have done the above steps which you mentioned above. 
I want to expand the "sda1" partition but it did not allow me to expand it. It allow me to expand other partition like "sda2"  and it allow me to create new partition. 
"Sda1" is the partition where my download item save and it is 1GB so the system gives me an error while downloading.
Now my question : 
should I delete the "sda1" partition ? and create new partition and make new partition primary ?
or what should I do ?

Comment: Deleting `sda1` would likely be “a bad thing”, as that’s probably where your OS is installed. If you were unable to resize the partition, there’s a possibility that you didn’t boot from a “live ISO” as you cannot resize a mounted partition 

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But I do boot from "live ISO" by setting the boot order from setting.

Comment: I have extended the space of "sda2" by following the below link : 
https://linuxhint.com/increase-virtualbox-disk-size/ 
Now I have enough space in "sda2", so my question is :
can I download & install my items in that place of disk (sda2)  ? like we download our items on any drive like C drive, D drive etc. 
NOTE: I have updated the question. Please see the current condition of disk.